# how to fix twig extension deprecation in symfony2.3

Tags: symfony

```
DEPRECATION - The Twig_Filter_Method class is deprecated since version 1.12 and will be removed in 2.0. Use Twig_SimpleFilter instead.


Called from require() at line 92
Called from DebugClassLoader::loadClass()
Called from spl_autoload_call() at line 42
Called from DoctrineExtension::getFilters() at line 3432
Called from Twig_Environment::initExtension() at line 3426
Called from Twig_Environment::initExtensions() at line 3377
Called from Twig_Environment::getUnaryOperators() at line 371
Called from Twig_Lexer::getOperatorRegex() at line 65
```

my symfony gets deprecated..
how to remove this?.. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is to find where you define a new filter in your twig extensions and replace the deprecated way of defining new filters with the new one. An example of how to do this is https://github.com/schmittjoh/serializer/pull/484/files

Comment: aww.. so what if the filter is on the twig ex bundle?